# Render PDF table documents from Word template in R Markdown

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown

I have a template from Word (see photo) that I would like to populate using an R data frame. The fields in the template marked with << >> match the field names from my data frame. I want to input the values from this data frame into the table and then render an individual pdf document for each << Group Name >>.

I have searched far and wide for a solution and have not found one. Can this be done in R Markdown?
[image: template example]

Answer (score 0):

Check out {redoc}: https://noamross.github.io/redoc/, but note that the author describes it as "in suspended animation". If that doesn't work, manually recreating your table using {flextable} is probably the way to go.